# An i386/x64 pop FS/GS instruction supports a variant where it increments the SP by 32 bits or 64 bits in stead of 16 bits. What is it used for?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, i386

According to the Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Volume 2 the `pop fs` supports 3 variants (the same goes for `pop gs`):

- Pop top of stack into FS; increment stack pointer by 16 bits.
- Pop top of stack into FS; increment stack pointer by 32 bits. (available in compat/leg mode)
- Pop top of stack into FS; increment stack pointer by 64 bits. (available in 64-Bit mode)

The AMD64 documentation op `pop` doesn't describe explicitly what happens to the stack pointer. I tried to produce those and it seems gas does recognise them (I assumed they need the 66h prefix):

```
 80490d6:       0f a1                   pop    fs
 80490d8:       66 0f a1                popw   fs
 80490db:       0f a9                   pop    gs
 80490dd:       66 0f a9                popw   gs
```

I'm breaking my head over these. To my understanding, the FS and GS registers are 16 bits, I know they have a hidden portion, but I don't expect the `pop` instruction to be able to manipulate those right? Can somebody explain what the purpose of these variant are?

Comment: To keep the stack aligned as expected for the current operating mode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In 32 bit mode, each stack slot is 32 bit.  It would be rather annoying if you had to adjust the stack pointer to a multiple of 4 bytes after pushing a segment register, so the CPU provides instructions to push segment registers into 4 byte stack slots.

When a segment register is pushed with operand size 32 bit, the register contents are zero-extended to a dword.  When it is popped, only the lower two byte are read into the segment register.  The upper two byte are again ignored.

Comment: Ah, that gave me an entry for some subsequent reading. I thought that stack access is always 16bit aligned and that is it. I didn't know that misaligned access to 32bit numbers cause a performance penalty.